# Woocommerce. Исключить товар со своей же страницы

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Здравствуйте.
Сейчас с помощью атрибутов вывожу дополнительный блок товаров на страничке товара.
Получается так, что главный товар отображается на своей же странице в дополнительных товарах.
Убрать этот атрибут с главного товара нельзя, потому что этот товар отображается как дополнительный в других товарах.
Как можно исключить его со своей же страницы?
Спасибо.

Comment: При запросе доп товаров поставить условие `WHERE id != {$currentId}`, как это реализовано в wp даже не знаю, вполне вероятно что придется писать свой запрос вместо стандартной функции.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Какой "главный" причём тут атрибуты для "доп. блоков товара". Дай скрин или ссылку. И расскажи как ты этот "блок" в атрибуты запихнул. Исправь вопрос.

Comment: @SeVlad, главный - это тот, чья страница открыта. И он же попадает в похожие на него.

Comment: @DaemonHK это называется post__not_in.

Comment: Покажите свой код вывода дополнительных товаров.

Comment: @Qwertiy это вопросы по ВП? По ВП. Давайте не будем фантазировать за ТСа, а дождёмся ответов.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/hqu4dw вот так это выглядит сейчас. вот по такому атрибуту формируется блок справа: http://prntscr.com/hqu4ku

Comment: @Qwertiy всё правильно понял

Comment: @SeVlad, это за тобой ^^

Comment: @ИгорьМарченков исправь вопрос. Картинки должны быть в теле вопроса и пояснения что к чему тоже. Ида. по картинкам не видно ответа на вопросы про атрибуты.